# Switching From Crypto Wallet Auth to Social Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, ethereum, web3js

I have built a product which has quite a number of users and the authentication method I used was Ethereum and Solana (meaning people connect their wallets to log in). However, I would like to switch to social auth based logins (e.g. google, twitter, etc.). What is the best way I can go about doing this whilst keeping the users account intact? In other words, how can I get existing users (who used their wallet addresses to log in) to connect their social account in order to log in from here onwards? What tools or what procedure should I take?

P.S. My stack is NextJS, NodeJs and Firebase for database.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have some form of persistence layer where you have stored user details when linking their crypto wallet to their account.

To add Oauth2 + PKCE based login, You can add additional fields in the User table to indicate {provider}-access and {provider}-refresh token. The provider here refers to your chosen provider like google. Subsequently, get your backend to initiate a Oauth2 flow with the provider (refer to their documentation) to get an authorisation token with the callback URL to your frontend.

The authorisation token should then be passed to the backend again so that they can be exchanged for access and refresh token with the provider. These access and refresh token which are then stored in your persistence layer.

The user account is linked so long as their refresh token remains valid, you can add a corn job or some other mechanism to refresh the tokens to keep the user's account linked.

There are other additional details regarding oauth2 flow that you can refer to:

[RFC 6749 The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749)

[RFS 7636 Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636)

[Proper Way of setting up Oauth2 - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647454/proper-way-of-setting-up-oauth2-for-authentication-for-microservices)

[OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics)